# Code::Blocks and Boost Asio. It just wont work

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio, codeblocks

I am having trouble getting Boost.Asio to compile in Code::Blocks. I installed and compiled Boost C++ Libraries and got both the given test examples to run. Now I am trying to get Boost.Asio to run.

Here is the compiler call:

`mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_49_0" -o bin\Debug\server.exe obj\Debug\server.o D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw44-mt-1_49.a D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_system-mgw44-mt-1_49.a`

And here is the output (see [this](http://imageshack.us/f/267/cdbideboost1.png/) link for more):

```
boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to 'WSAStartup@8'
boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:48: undefined reference to 'WSAStartup@0'
boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipps:50: undefined reference to 'WSASetLastError@4'
boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipps:178: undefined reference to 'GetAcceptExSockaddrs@32'
boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipps:296: undefined reference to 'closesocket@4'
```

Here is the code:

```
//
// server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2012 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/aligned_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

// Class to manage the memory to be used for handler-based custom allocation.
// It contains a single block of memory which may be returned for allocation
// requests. If the memory is in use when an allocation request is made, the
// allocator delegates allocation to the global heap.
class handler_allocator
  : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
  handler_allocator()
    : in_use_(false)
  {
  }

  void* allocate(std::size_t size)
  {
    if (!in_use_ && size < storage_.size)
    {
      in_use_ = true;
      return storage_.address();
    }
    else
    {
      return ::operator new(size);
    }
  }

  void deallocate(void* pointer)
  {
    if (pointer == storage_.address())
    {
      in_use_ = false;
    }
    else
    {
      ::operator delete(pointer);
    }
  }

private:
  // Storage space used for handler-based custom memory allocation.
  boost::aligned_storage<1024> storage_;

  // Whether the handler-based custom allocation storage has been used.
  bool in_use_;
};

// Wrapper class template for handler objects to allow handler memory
// allocation to be customised. Calls to operator() are forwarded to the
// encapsulated handler.
template <typename Handler>
class custom_alloc_handler
{
public:
  custom_alloc_handler(handler_allocator& a, Handler h)
    : allocator_(a),
      handler_(h)
  {
  }

  template <typename Arg1>
  void operator()(Arg1 arg1)
  {
    handler_(arg1);
  }

  template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
  void operator()(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
  {
    handler_(arg1, arg2);
  }

  friend void* asio_handler_allocate(std::size_t size,
      custom_alloc_handler<Handler>* this_handler)
  {
    return this_handler->allocator_.allocate(size);
  }

  friend void asio_handler_deallocate(void* pointer, std::size_t /*size*/,
      custom_alloc_handler<Handler>* this_handler)
  {
    this_handler->allocator_.deallocate(pointer);
  }

private:
  handler_allocator& allocator_;
  Handler handler_;
};

// Helper function to wrap a handler object to add custom allocation.
template <typename Handler>
inline custom_alloc_handler<Handler> make_custom_alloc_handler(
    handler_allocator& a, Handler h)
{
  return custom_alloc_handler<Handler>(a, h);
}

class session
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
        make_custom_alloc_handler(allocator_,
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read,
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
          make_custom_alloc_handler(allocator_,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_write,
              shared_from_this(),
              boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
          make_custom_alloc_handler(allocator_,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read,
              shared_from_this(),
              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }
  }

private:
  // The socket used to communicate with the client.
  tcp::socket socket_;

  // Buffer used to store data received from the client.
  boost::array<char, 1024> data_;

  // The allocator to use for handler-based custom memory allocation.
  handler_allocator allocator_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<session> session_ptr;

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    session_ptr new_session(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session_ptr new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
    }

    new_session.reset(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here are some images concerning my problem.

http://imageshack.us/f/267/cdbideboost1.png

http://imageshack.us/f/833/cdbideboost3.png

http://imageshack.us/f/31/cdbideboost4.png

http://imageshack.us/f/525/cdbideboost5.png

Comment: This is a linking problem, you should check path in `Link Libraries`(second screenshot). Make sure these paths contain asio libs.

Comment: There are no .a asio libs in the lib folder.

Comment: Post your error message as text in the question. Questions which depend on off-site links to be answerable are not acceptable here.

Comment: And that means what? The picture links are not acceptable?

Comment: @user1509040: While not required, it is preferred to have all relevant information in the post.  Links can break over time, potentially rendering them useless to future viewers.

Comment: I was too low of a rep level to post images and uploading them would have resulted in too low of a resolution to read.

Answer (score 11):

Link to library wsock32 as well as ws2_32

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The linker error message indicates that you need to link against the WinSock library.  Boost.Asio is a header file only library; thus, there will be no `boost_asio` library to link against.

---

The following example program is designed to introduce dependencies on the WinSock library.

`example.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{
  WSAStartup(WORD(), LPWSADATA());
  WSACleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling `example.cpp`, but not linking to the WinSock library, the following errors occur:

```
C:\example>mingw32-g++.exe example.cpp
example.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
example.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I link against `ws2_32`, the references are resolved:

```
C:\example>mingw32-g++.exe example.cpp -lws2_32

C:\example>dir /B
a.exe
example.cpp
```

Also note that the order in which the files are specified matters.  Libraries must be specified after the names of all dependent modules.  In this case, `example.cpp` is dependent on `ws2_32`; therefore, `ws2_32` must appear after `example.cpp`.

```
C:\example>mingw32-g++.exe -lws2_32 example.cpp
example.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
example.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Where would i find that? Sorry if I am slow to catch on.

Comment: @user1509040: I believe it is distributed with mingw.  Try adding `ws2_32` to the list of libraries being linked.

Comment: There are three WS2_32 under Microsoft SDK libraries and under two sub-folders: IA64 and x64. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jakekaz: You will need to provide more details on what you have already tried.  Compiler calls and error messages would be helpful.  In any case, I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in server ---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_49_0"  -o bin\Debug\server.exe obj\Debug\server.o    D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw44-mt-1_49.a D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_system-mgw44-mt-1_49.a "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\WS2_32.Lib" 
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:178: undefined reference to `GetAcceptExSockaddrs@32'
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files

Comment: (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:494: undefined reference to `AcceptEx@32'
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:519: undefined reference to `AcceptEx@32'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
3 errors, 0 warnings

Comment: The `GetAcceptExSockaddrs` function is part of the `Mswsock.lib` library.  You can try googling for undefined references and determine what library they are in.  Also, does adding `-lws2_32` to the compile give the same results?

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Code::Blocks.  However, there should be a `libws2_32.a` distributed with mingw.

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in server ---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_49_0"  -o bin\Debug\server.exe obj\Debug\server.o    D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw44-mt-1_49.a D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_system-mgw44-mt-1_49.a D:\CodeBlocksIDE\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libws2_32.a 
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:178: undefined reference to `GetAcceptExSockaddrs@32'
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files

Comment: (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:494: undefined reference to `AcceptEx@32'
obj\Debug\server.o:C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_49_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:519: undefined reference to `AcceptEx@32'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
3 errors, 0 warnings

Comment: Says something about "-lmswsock" in this link:   http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/building-errors-shared-ptr-hpp-253-undefined-reference-to-AcceptEx-32-td2562637.html Is this any help?

Answer (score 0):

I`m newbe in codding yet.  I have just solved the "C::B" Boost ASIO configuration problem with my simple test file where this library is used under Windows. I am using tdm-gcc-64 v10.3.0.

I was getting compilation and linking errors:

```
undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem was that the linker did not see instruction of linking (with Code::Blocks) to the Windows API library ws2_32.lib, which is needed for winsock2.h, and which is located in the OS system directories and, as various forums have shown, it is necessary to indicate this to the linker in "Other linker options" in the project Build settings. "General settings -> Compiler" I didn't touch - I left everything empty there.

And everything fell into place this way:
I wrote the headers in a certain order - the compiler was swearing about it:

```
#include <iostream>

#include<winsock2.h>
//#include<winsock.h>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ts/internet.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace asio;
int main()
{
    WSAStartup(WORD(), LPWSADATA());
    WSACleanup();
    cout<<"ASIOTest"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I configured Code::Blocks this way. Suddenly it turned out that Code::Blocks understands the linker flag if the "Other linker options" field is used for it. Otherwise it doesn't work.

[ws2_32.lib system directory list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c2Eu.png)

[My global OS variable %BOOST_ROOT% is: D:\DEV\boost_1_80_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2WZQ.png)

["-lws2_32" - add this in other linker options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neSs4.png)

[Compiller directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSbg.png)

[Linker directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0r5L.png)

[Compiler flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPabi.png)

And my application was successfully compiled and linked.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in BoostASIOTest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -O3 -Wall -std=c++14 -m32 -Og -ID:\DEV\boost_1_80_0 -ID:\DEV\boost_1_80_0 -ID:\DEV\boost_1_80_0 -ID:\DEV\boost_1_80_0 -c D:\DEV\Test\BoostASIOTest\BoostASIOTest\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe -LD:\DEV\boost_1_80_0\stage\lib -LD:\DEV\boost_1_80_0\stage\lib -LD:\DEV\boost_1_80_0\stage\lib -o bin\Debug\BoostASIOTest.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -static-libstdc++ -m32 -lws2_32  
Output file is bin\Debug\BoostASIOTest.exe with size 2.03 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))
```